# Solve the maximization problem involving summation

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, dynamic-programming, programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am currently working on the following problem:

> Let $T \geq 1$ be some finite integer. Solve the following
> maximization problem: $$ \max \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{2^t} \sqrt{x_t}
> \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad \sum_{t=1}^T x_t \leq 1, x_t \geq 0 \;
> \forall t $$

Can I just write that constraint is binding? Somehow I get the incorrect answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823530/maximize-sum-t-1t-left-frac12-rightt-sqrtt?rq=1)

**Dynamic Programming**
Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_T)$ and define the objective by $J(x) = \sum_{t=1}^T{\sqrt{x_t}/2^t}$. We want to find the $\arg\max\{J(x) \mid \sum_t{x_t} \leq 1, x_t \geq 0\}$.
As $J$ is increasing in each $x_t$, the constraint is binding such that $x_T = 1 - \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}{x_t}$.
Let $J_\tau(x_1,\ldots,x_{T-1}) = \sum_{t=\tau}^T{\sqrt{x_t}/2^t}$.
Now you may recursively solve from the second to final problem to the initial problem.
Consider for example
\begin{align}
x_{T-1}^*(x_1,\ldots,x_{T-2}) &= \arg\max_{x_{T-1}}\left\{J_{T-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{T-1}) = \frac{\sqrt{x_{T-1}}}{2^{T-1}} + \frac{\sqrt{1 - \sum_{t=1}^{T-1}{x_t}}}{2^T}\right\}\\
&=\frac{4}{5}\left(1- \sum_{t=1}^{T-2}{x_t}\right)
.
\end{align}
Then each maximizer on each stage is a function of the previous actions.
Generally
\begin{align}
 x_\tau^*(x_1,\ldots,x_{\tau-1}) &= \arg\max_{x_\tau}J_\tau(x_1,\ldots,x_\tau,x_{\tau+1}^*(x_1,\ldots,x_\tau),x_{\tau+2}^*(x_1,\ldots,x_\tau,x_{\tau+1}^*(x_1,\ldots,x_\tau)), \ldots).
\end{align}
Eventually, at $t = 1$ you would only need to pick $x_1$.

**Lagrange**
Let $L(x,\lambda) = J(x) + \lambda(1-\sum_{t=1}^{T}{x_t})$.
Optimality conditions
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial x_t} = \frac{1}{2^{t+1}\sqrt{x_t}} - \lambda = 0,\\
&\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial \lambda} = 1-\sum_{t=1}^{T}{x_t} = 0.
\end{align}
Solving the first equation for $x_t$ yields
\begin{align}
x_t = \frac{1}{2^{2(t+1)}\lambda^2}.
\end{align}
Summing over $t$
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=1}^{T}{x_t} = \sum_{t=1}^{T}{\frac{1}{2^{2(t+1)}\lambda^2}} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad 1 = \frac{4^T - 1}{3 \cdot 4^{T+1} \lambda^2}.
\end{align}
Solving for $\lambda^2$ an substituting in the first optimality condition eventually yields
\begin{align}
x_t = \frac{3 \cdot 4^{T+1}}{2^{2(t+1)}(4^T - 1)}.
\end{align}